# Why does my dnsmasq refuse DNS queries from its own local DHCP clients?

Tags: networking, router, dns, dnsmasq

I have set up `dnsmasq` on a Linux machine acting as a simple NAT-based router. The internal machines are getting assigned an IP and they have working internet access *except* that DNS queries are not resolved.

The router machine's internal address is `10.42.0.1`. One of the clients is assigned `10.42.0.101`.

On the client machine:

```
user@client:~$ dig google.com @10.42.0.1
...
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 18466
...
```

Wireshark confirms that the query is received by 10.42.0.1 and immediately refused via DNS response.

### Contents of `/etc/dnsmasq.d/nat-clients`

(MAC addresses anonymized)

```
bind-interfaces
no-hosts
strict-order

except-interface=lo
listen-address=10.42.0.1

dhcp-range=10.42.0.10,10.42.0.100,12h
dhcp-option=option:router,10.42.0.1
dhcp-host=00:11:22:33:44:55,billy,10.42.0.101
dhcp-host=55:66:77:88:99:00,sally,10.42.0.102
```

Additionally, `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` is only comments.

### Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` on the router

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.0.5
nameserver 10.0.0.6
search domain.company.com
```

### Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` on the client

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.42.0.1
```

**Am I missing a configuration directive that allows `dnsmasq` to forward/resolve client DNS queries?**